# Visual Studio 2012 csproj and sqlproj

Tags: visual-studio-2012, csproj

I have the latest VS 2012 RC and when I try to open an existing soulution that was written by another programmer in VS 2012, it says that the files csproj and sqlproj are incompatible with the version I am running.  Any ideas why?

Comment: Please provide more information. For instance, which version of VS2012 did the other developer use? RC? Which editions are you using? Ultimate?

Comment: I am using ultimate RC; I would assume that I should be able to open every type file.  I can open it on my laptop which has Dreamspark VS2012 pro.  I don't want to put that on the company computer.  The only answer I get from him is VS2012, he doesn't know if its Ultimate, etc.

Comment: Did you upgrade from beta to RC?

Comment: Ask him to use Help->About and let you know. At this late stage in the development of the product, I strongly doubt that this is a problem that happens to everyone, or every time.

Comment: When I open my version it doesn't say that its ultimate.  But that is the package i downloaded.

Comment: Problem solved, my company has finally ordered a full version.

Answer (score 3):

Install the [Sql Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500335%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) for VS. Available from the [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) or the SQL Server installer.

Comment: Download for SSDT can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027). I couldn't find it on WPI.